# ASP.NET MVC Hashing Sensitive Data (EF)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, hash

My client requires me to store certain database information hashed. Since Entity Framework hashes account passwords by default, is there a quick and easy way to hash other database columns as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to Encrypt : [Encryption Example](https://gist.github.com/albertbori/e95860644e69c1572441)

You can than add attribute `[Encrypted]` to the properties you want to encrypt

Comment: Encryption and hashing are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

A hash is a one-way function. Hashing something renders it irretrievable - as in, the actual value can never be recreated.

For passwords, this is exactly what you want, because you never need to display a user's password to them, you just need to check they typed the correct one. For most data, you need to be able to use it. Therefore, what you're looking for is encryption, not hashing.

Have a look at AES256 for encrypting the data before it goes into the database. You might also consider transparent data encryption, if you're using a managed database. Note that if you encrypt the values that go in yourself, you won't be able to query on them or index them - so you can only do it for values that you don't need to look up.